# jQuery Raty Average Submit and Update

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm using jQuery Raty plugin for one my projects.

http://wbotelhos.com/raty/

Here is the code i'm using

HTML

```
<div id="rate<?php echo $row['id'];?>"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('#rate<?php echo $fRow['id'];?>').raty({score:<?php echo $row['rate'];?>});
});
</script>
```

What i like to know is how to update the rating (take the database value and update with the new rating) using Ajax.

Comment: This is very broad. What have you tried? Do you have a specific technical question?

Comment: when do you want to update the rating..i mean to say time . for every 10 min or page loads like that